# What is C# equivalent for this C line of code?

Tags: c#, c

I need to rewrite some C function on C#, I have done some progress, but met something that I don't understand.
Usually I ask "what is this?", but in this case I must ask "What the hell is this?!"

I added comment above the line that I don't understand.

```
static enumError conv_from_CMPR
(
    Image_t     * dest_img, // valid destination
    const Image_t   * src_img,  // valid source
    image_format_t  iform       // new image format, only valid IMG_X_*
)
{
    DASSERT(dest_img);
    DASSERT(src_img);
    DASSERT( src_img->iform == IMG_CMPR );
    DASSERT( iform >= IMG_X__MIN && iform <= IMG_X__MAX );

    const uint bits_per_pixel   = 4;
    const uint block_width  = 8;
    const uint block_height = 8;

    uint h_blocks, v_blocks, img_size;
    enumError err = CalcImageBlock(src_img,
                bits_per_pixel, block_width, block_height,
                &h_blocks, &v_blocks, &img_size, false );
    if (err)
    return err;

    //This is the line that I don't know how to convert to C#.
    //Ok, u16 is looks like a numeric type, but what happens next I don't have any idea. I don't see where is variable name.
    u16 (*rd16) ( const void * data_ptr ) = src_img->endian->rd16;

    uint data_size;
    u8 * data = AllocDataIMG(src_img,4,&data_size);
    u8 * dest1 = data;
    const u8 *src = src_img->data;

    const uint block_size = block_width * 4;
    const uint line_size  = EXPAND8(src_img->width) * 4;
    const uint delta[] = { 0, 16, 4*line_size, 4*line_size+16 };

    while ( v_blocks-- > 0 )
    {
    u8 * dest2 = dest1;
    uint hblk = h_blocks;
    while ( hblk-- > 0 )
    {
        uint subb;
        for ( subb = 0; subb < 4; subb++ )
        {
        u8 palette[4][4], *pal = palette[0];

        const u16 val1 = rd16(src);
        src += 2;
        *pal++ = cc58[ val1 >> 11 & 0x1f ];
        *pal++ = cc68[ val1 >>  5 & 0x3f ];
        *pal++ = cc58[ val1       & 0x1f ];
        *pal++ = 0xff;

        const u16 val2 = rd16(src);
        src += 2;
        *pal++ = cc58[ val2 >> 11 & 0x1f ];
        *pal++ = cc68[ val2 >>  5 & 0x3f ];
        *pal++ = cc58[ val2       & 0x1f ];
        *pal++ = 0xff;

        if ( val1 > val2 )
        {
            *pal++ = ( 2 * palette[0][0] + palette[1][0] ) / 3;
            *pal++ = ( 2 * palette[0][1] + palette[1][1] ) / 3;
            *pal++ = ( 2 * palette[0][2] + palette[1][2] ) / 3;
            *pal++ = 0xff;

            *pal++ = ( 2 * palette[1][0] + palette[0][0] ) / 3;
            *pal++ = ( 2 * palette[1][1] + palette[0][1] ) / 3;
            *pal++ = ( 2 * palette[1][2] + palette[0][2] ) / 3;
            *pal++ = 0xff;
        }
        else
        {
            *pal++ = ( palette[0][0] + palette[1][0] ) / 2;
            *pal++ = ( palette[0][1] + palette[1][1] ) / 2;
            *pal++ = ( palette[0][2] + palette[1][2] ) / 2;
            *pal++ = 0xff;

            *pal++ = 0;
            *pal++ = 0;
            *pal++ = 0;
            *pal++ = 0;
        }

        u8 *dest3 = dest2 + delta[subb];
        uint i;
        for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
        {
            u8 val = *src++;
            memcpy(dest3+12, palette[ val & 3 ], 4); val >>= 2;
            memcpy(dest3+ 8, palette[ val & 3 ], 4); val >>= 2;
            memcpy(dest3+ 4, palette[ val & 3 ], 4); val >>= 2;
            memcpy(dest3   , palette[ val & 3 ], 4);
            dest3 += line_size;
        }
        }
        dest2 += block_size;
    }
    dest1 += line_size * block_height;
    }

    DASSERT( src == src_img->data + img_size );
    DASSERT( dest1 <= data + data_size );
    AssignDataRGB(dest_img,src_img,data);
    dest_img->alpha_status = 0;
    return ERR_OK;
}
```

Comment: Don't add unrelated tags.

Comment: Hint: `rd16`is a function pointer.

Comment: Delegates ftw is what it is.

Comment: Its a prime example of why people switch to C#

Comment: @MichaelWalz - I don't understand. So, the variable name should be `data_ptr`, but what's it's type then? There is u16 and then you told rd16 is a function pointer. So what is variable's type?

Comment: No. The variable is `rd16`, that is a function pointer that points to a function like: `u16 test (const void *)` `u16` should be `UInt16` in [tag:c#]

Comment: @Kosmos you must understand the concept of function pointers. As long as you don't know what a function pointer is, discussion is pointless. Google "stackoverflow function pointer".

Comment: For [tag:c#] take a loom at [this guide about delegates](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_delegates.htm)

Comment: Ok, I got it. I simply need to track what function is called and use it without this function pointer. Thanks everyone. Make some answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: While not a well written question (hence the down votes), it is a very interesting question (hence my up vote).  Perhaps explain what you've done to try and understand the problem, what your theory is, etc., and get rid of superfluous code, only leaving parts relevant to the variables at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You line of code would be a delegate in C# [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173172.aspx)

If you have LOTS of C code (as DLLs) and you need to use them from C#, then you may want to consider preserving the C and using COM Interop through tlbimp. [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/697w37zd(v=vs.110).aspx)